# Functions and subselects in single FLWOR

Tags: xml, performance, xquery

I'm writing an XQuery to analyse large numbers of XML files that store queries similar to the example below. For these queries I'd like to calculate averages, sums and other information on various subelements. Additionally I'd like to generate subsections of the queries in the same document, for instance all queries that have no hits.

As I'll be manipulating hundreds of thousands of XML files, I'd like to make my xquery as efficient as possible. I've tried to use a single `for` iteration across the documents but I simply cannot figure out how to derive all the information I need.

Here's a sample XML:

```
<Query>
  <QueryString>Gigabyte Sapphire GTX-860</QueryString>
  <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
  <QueryTime>0.04669069110297385</QueryTime>
  <Hits>8</Hits>
  <Date>2013-05-02</Date>
  <Time>12:07:07</Time>
  <LastModified>12:07:07</LastModified>
  <Pages resultsPerPage="10" clickCount="2">
    <Page resultCount="8" visited="true">
      <Result index="1" clickIndex="0" timeViewed="0" pid="85405" title="DDR3 1024 MB" />
      <Result index="2" clickIndex="1" timeViewed="178" pid="54065" title="ATK Excellium&#x9;" />
      <Result index="3" clickIndex="0" timeViewed="0" pid="74902" title="Intel E9650" />
      <Result index="4" clickIndex="0" timeViewed="0" pid="56468" title="ASUS Radeon HD 7980" />
      <Result index="5" clickIndex="0" timeViewed="0" pid="31072" title="Intel E7500" />
      <Result index="6" clickIndex="0" timeViewed="0" pid="26620" title="DDR3 2048 MB" />
      <Result index="7" clickIndex="2" timeViewed="92" pid="55625" title="Gigabyte Sapphire 7770" />
      <Result index="8" clickIndex="0" timeViewed="0" pid="67701" title="Intel E9650" />
    </Page>
  </Pages>
</Query>
```

Here's the XQuery:

```
let $doc := collection('file:///C:/REP/XML/input?select=*.xml')
for $y in (
    <Queries>
    {
        for $x in $doc
        let $hits := $x/Query/Hits
        return <Query hits="{$hits}" >{$x/Query/QueryString/string()}</Query>
    }
    </Queries>
)
let $avgHits := avg(data($y/Query/@hits))
let $numQueries := count($y/*)
return <Statistics avgHits="{$avgHits}" numQueries="{$numQueries}"/>
```

Which correctly returns `<Statistics numQueries="10" avgHits="19.7"/>` for a sample of 10 XML files. Is this the right approach? I seem to need the double for so I can group the Queries from disjoint files together as I can't seem to run functions on them otherwise.

I also need to repeat some queries inside the created `<Statistics>` element. Do I need to repeat a FLWOR statement? I can't bring summed or averaged values outside the for statement that calculates them yet I can't calculate them *and* perform a subselect since I'll have to include a where to filter them.

(**Update**)This is the query that I've come up with to include subsections of the queries, but as I mentioned I'm worried about the performance.

```
let $doc := collection('file:///C:/REP/XML/input?select=*.xml')
for $y in (
    <Queries>
    {
        for $x in $doc
        let $hits := $x/Query/Hits
        return <Query hits="{$hits}" >{$x/Query/QueryString/string()}</Query>
    }
    </Queries>
)
let $avgHits := avg(data($y/Query/@hits))
let $numQueries := count($y/*)
return <Statistics avgHits="{$avgHits}" numQueries="{$numQueries}">
    {
    for $x in $doc
    let $hits := $x/Query/Hits
    where $x/Query/Hits < 10
    return <Query hits="{$hits}" >{$x/Query/QueryString/string()}</Query>
    }   
</Statistics>
```

Will the XQuery processor optimise my for statements or will it access all XML files with every for that loops across them? Will the first `let` statement prevent this?

This is the kind of document I'm aiming to generate:

```
<DailyStats date="2013-04-15" >
    <DayStats>
        <QueryCount>24644</QueryCount>
        <Errors>0</Errors>
        <EmptySearches>643</EmptySearches>
        <AverageSearchTime>0.0213</AverageSearchTime>
        <AverageSearchesPerHour>236</AverageSearchesPerHour>
    </DayStats>
    <StoredQueries>
        <FailedSearches>
            <FailedSearch time="23:33:34" query="blurey" searchTime="0.0524" />
        </FailedSearches>
    </StoredQueries>
</DailyStats>
```

Comment: What processor are you using? If you are worried about performance you should use an XML database (if you not already do so) as it will improve performance by indexing the data. Additionally, e.g. using BaseX and loading your XML files into a database you can access all nodes using ```db:open("your-db")```` avoiding the nested for loops. Additionally you could use some database-specific indexes which will speed up your query. If you have a simple XQuery precessor working on the fs it will certainly touch each xml file as it knows nothing about the data in each file.

Comment: Apart from that, your XQuery looks basically fine to me. Optimization, as I tried to point out, heavily depends on the processor/database you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It seems I'm stuck in a bit of circular logic as the technology we'll be using depends on the performance we get. An XML database for instance won't be considered unless performance is too poor when the files are simply stored on a file system. Transformation will take place through Apache Camel which likely means Saxon. I just ran the above query through the EditiX Saxon processor and it seems to take less than a minute to parse 100 000 thousand documents. I'll have to see whether extra for constructions impact the runtime.

Comment: Yeah, you will have to run some test, it is nearly impossible to say anything about real-time runtime, because it heavily depends on the data and the query you have. However, it shouldn't be too hard to swicht to a database later on, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: @dirkk Thank you for the advice. If you can turn your recommendation to test the script and scale technologies based on the resulting performance into an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but rewriting stuff seems like redundant work to me and I really don't care about these reputation points at SO. And every other user with the same or a similar problem can also get some insights from the comments, so I guess its fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you are worried about performance you should use an XML database (if you not already do so) as it will improve performance by indexing the data. Additionally, e.g. using BaseX and loading your XML files into a database you can access all nodes using ```db:open("your-db")```` avoiding the nested for loops. Additionally you could use some database-specific indexes which will speed up your query. If you have a simple XQuery precessor working on the fs it will certainly touch each xml file as it knows nothing about the data in each file.
>
> Apart from that, your XQuery looks basically fine to me. Optimization, as I tried to point out, heavily depends on the processor/database you are using.
>
> Yeah, you will have to run some test, it is nearly impossible to say anything about real-time runtime, because it heavily depends on the data and the query you have. However, it shouldn't be too hard to swicht to a database later on, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.